# Web Scraping - transfermarkt most valuable players

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am new at web scraping.

I cannot find my fault in this very code:

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/spieler- 
statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop"
response=requests.get(url)
html_icerigi=response.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(html_icerigi,"html.parser")
footballer = soup.find_all("a",{"class":"spielprofil_tooltip tooltipstered"})
footballer_list=[]
for footballer in footballer_list:
   footballer=footballer.text
    footballer=footballer.strip()
    footballer=footballer.replace("\n","")
    footballer_list.append(["Futbolcu:{}".format(footballer)])
print(footballer_list)
```

Comment: you're trying to get html dynamic page I believe. You might need to use Selenium

Comment: actually i'm not getting error message but there no object in list "footballer_list"

Comment: oh i get it. thank you

Answer (score 3):

It doable with `BeautifulSoup` and here the problem

1. It has anti scraper, need to set request user agent
2. Class of `tooltipstered` is appended
   dynamically you can remove it.
3. Use `response.text` instead of escaped string `response.content`.
4. You are iterating empty list not list of `a` elements

   ```
   footballer_list=[]
   for footballer in footballer_list:
   ```
5. Unneeded multiline variable rewrite and maybe wrong list tree, did you mean want to
   append dict instead of

   ```
   [['Futbolcu:Kylian Mbappé'], ......, ['Futbolcu:Marlon Freitas']]
   ```

fixed code:

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop"
heads = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=heads)
html_icerigi = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_icerigi, "html.parser")
footballers = soup.find_all("a",{"class":"spielprofil_tooltip"})
footballer_list = []
for footballer in footballers:
    footballer_list.append({"Futbolcu" : footballer.text.strip()})

print(footballer_list)
print(footballer_list[5]["Futbolcu"])
```

Results:

```
[
 {'Futbolcu': 'Kylian Mbappé'}, 
 ......., 
 {'Futbolcu': 'Marlon Freitas'}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

install [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and then access it that way. otherwise, your code seems to work

```
import bs4 
from selenium import webdriver 

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop')

html_icerigi = browser.page_source

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_icerigi,"html.parser")

footballer = soup.find_all("a",{"class":"spielprofil_tooltip tooltipstered"})
footballer_list=[]

for footballer in footballer_list:
    footballer=footballer.text
    footballer=footballer.strip()
    footballer=footballer.replace("\n","")
    footballer_list.append(["Futbolcu:{}".format(footballer)])
print(footballer)

browser.close()
```

output:

```
[<a class="spielprofil_tooltip tooltipstered" href="/kylian-mbappe/profil/spieler/342229" id="342229">Kylian Mbappé</a>, <a class="spielprofil_tooltip tooltipstered" href="/neymar/profil/spieler/68290" id="68290">Neymar</a>, <a class="spielprofil_tooltip tooltipstered" href="/lionel-messi/profil/spieler/28003" id="28003">Lionel Messi</a>, <a class="spielprofil_tooltip tooltipstered" href="/mohamed-salah/profil/spieler/148455" id="148455">Mohamed Salah</a>, <a...
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from `selenium`, you also can use `requests_html` to render page. Though you are asking why you did not gain anything, your `for-loop` is wrong. It means you will get empty `footballer_list` at last, even you already ran JavaScript and got full html code.

```
import requests_html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop"
with requests_html.HTMLSession() as s:
    resp = s.get(url)
    resp.html.render()
    page = resp.html.raw_html


soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"html.parser")
footballer_all = soup.find_all("a",{"class":"spielprofil_tooltip tooltipstered"})

footballer_list = []

for footballer in footballer_all:
    footballer = footballer.text
    footballer = footballer.strip()
    footballer = footballer.replace("\n","")
    footballer_list.append(["Futbolcu:{}".format(footballer)])

print(footballer_list)
```